# How do I create a template that contains proprietary components?

Tags: templates, branch

I need some advice about creating a template.  I need to create a template with all the components on the page, each component has to be unique and not related to another copy (asides from header, navigation and footer).

I've tried using standard values on my template then creating a branch template with a datasource.  The problem is if I add or remove a component from the standard values this doesn't update the branch template, but it does update any instances of my item.  If I update the branch template this doesn't change any instances.

How would you resolve this issue, would you just put all the fields that are fixed onto the template?

Comment: Do you use SXA? If yes you could leverage Snippet functionality to achieve your goals precisely

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by implementing a custom pipeline that will change Data Sources on all renderings when new branch template is instantiated.  So it will adjust all the paths for renderings to point to a newly created sub items.  See more here:

https://kamsar.net/index.php/2016/03/Branch-Datasource-Presets/

Note: there was some sort of small bug that would not change DataSource for one of the renderings, and I can't remember what was the issue...